# can i call time based trigger on gmail add-ons?

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, gmail-api, gmail-addons

I am creating gmail add-ons. Is there any way to call a time based
trigger per user when a user installs add-ons?

```
function getMail(){
  var interval = 5;   
  var date = new Date();
  var timeFrom = Math.floor(date.valueOf()/1000) - 60 * interval;
  var threads = GmailApp.search('is:inbox after:' + timeFrom);
  var emailAddress = Gmail.Users.getProfile("me").emailAddress;
  for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++)
 {
    var data=Gmail.Users.Messages.get(emailAddress,threads[i].getId(), 
    {format: "RAW"}).raw;
    var signature =Utilities.newBlob(data).getDataAsString();
     Logger.log(signature);
}
  }
function trigger(){
  ScriptApp.newTrigger("getMail").timeBased().everyMinutes(1).create();

}

function onInstall(e){
  trigger();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is no. They do not allow the creation of triggers from the gmail add on. Further information can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/gmail/add-ons/guides/restrictions) at the restrictions page.